# Throttling semaphore http-server C#

Tags: c#, throttling

My task: Organize the stability of the server under the load exceeding its capabilities.

Here is the code:

```
private async Task HandleOneRequest(HttpListenerContext listenerContext)
{
   // one request processing
    await Task.CompletedTask;
} 

 private async Task HandleContextAsync(HttpListenerContext listenerContext)
    {
        var allTasks = new List<Task>();
        var queue = new Queue<HttpListenerContext>();
        queue.Enqueue(listenerContext);
        if (queue.Count > 50) // the number 50 is taken approximately
        {
         // many request
        }
        else
        {
            using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(Environment.ProcessorCount, Environment.ProcessorCount))
            {
                foreach (var request in queue)
                {
                    await throttler.WaitAsync();
                    allTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await HandleOneRequest(queue.Dequeue());
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            throttler.Release();
                        }
                    }));
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
            }

        }
    }
```

Am I using the semaphore correctly? How else can you implement throttling http-server? Is the request queue created correctly?

Comment: You're not doing _anything_ correctly. 1) Your queing in `HandleContextAsync` makes no sense  2) Each call to `HandleContextAsync` will create its own semaphore  3) What's the point of `throttler.WaitAsync`?  4) What's the point of spinning up explicit threads only to block on them?

Comment: While you certainly can do this in c#, I strongly suggest you to not try to. Instead, either use one of the available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rate+limit or better yet, add an nginx in front of your application and let it do that, as it's much better equipped to do it.

Comment: Loading issue is usually due to the underlining TCP transport layer.  Check Task Manager and see if a memory leak is occurring.  When TCP is getting overloaded it doesn't ack each TCP message quick enough so messages get sent by client multiple times and then server as to remove the duplicates which adds to the work load.  The solution is to remove work from the server.  Make the server dedicated to just the one application.